# constexpr discrepancy between gcc8.2 and (intel) icc19.0.1

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, metaprogramming, icc

The following code compiles on gcc 8.2 but fails to compile on icc 19.0.1:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Type, typename... TypeList>
constexpr size_t f(std::tuple<TypeList...> const &){
    return 0;
}

template <typename Type, typename Tuple>
size_t g(Tuple && t){
    static size_t constexpr v= f<Type>(t);
    return v;
}

size_t h(){
    std::tuple<int> tuple;
    return g<int>(tuple);
}
```

The error I receive from icc is:

```
error: expression must have a constant value
static size_t constexpr v = f<Type>(t);
                            ^
note: the value of parameter "t" cannot be used as a constant
```

Intel's compiler is correct in that 't' is generally unknown and cannot be used as a constant. However, only the type of 't', which **is** known at compile-time, is used (to define the template parameter pack 'TypeList').

Why is this allowed in gcc but not in icc? Which compiler is correct?

Comment: `clang` and `msvc` also reject this code.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer my question of who is correct and why, but here is a (slightly less elegant) workaround that works on both compilers. I'll be happy to hear if anyone knows a better solution.

```
template <typename Type, typename Tuple, size_t... Indices>
constexpr size_t f(std::index_sequence<Indices...> const &){
    // TypeList is now 'std::tuple_element_t<Indices, TTuple>...'
    return 0;
}
template <typename Type, typename Tuple>
constexpr size_t f(){
    using BareTuple = std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple> >;
    return f<Type, BareTuple>
        (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<BareTuple>>{});
}
template <typename Type, typename Tuple>
constexpr size_t g(Tuple && t){
    size_t constexpr occurrences = f<Type, Tuple>();
    return occurrences;
}
...
```